# Как переопределить вывод изображений на сайте PHP

Tags: php

Имеется ресурс в котором все фотки выводим по jpg, каким образом посредством php смогу предопределить вывод всех фоток не затрагивая базу, допустим вывод site.ru/image.jpg сделать site.ru/image.png (на лету менять формат). Я новичок пока, прошу помочь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вы чего сделать то хотите, переконвертить прям картинку налету в другой формат? или просто чтобы вместо одного файла отдавался другой? если первый отсутствует, например